# Allowed memory size of bytes exhausted every 20 min | PDOStatement | Laravel | Live Server

Tags: php, laravel

My laravel project recently started throwing this error every 20 min. for 2 days already. I have not done any updates.

```
[2022-11-23 09:40:04] production.ERROR: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted 
(tried to allocate 1478656 bytes) {"exception":"[object] 
(Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException(code: 1): Allowed memory size of 
268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1478656 bytes) at 
/usr/www/users/webuser/admin/Example-Admin- 
PHP/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php:129)
[stacktrace]
#0 {main}
"}
```

I cannot increase the `memory_limit` in the `php.ini`. Thats not a real solution. I don't know why every other thread recommends it.

The error occurs exactly every 20 min, but I do not have any cronjobs configured. Could it be something related to laravel? I use laravel 5.8. PHP version on the server is: 7.2

My stacktrace looks like this:

```
[stacktrace]
#0 {main}
"}
```

Any code I could add somewhere to improve the logs?

Also it seems that nothing is broken, eventhough I currently see the error every 20 min. Everything works find and fast on the live site, how is this possible?

Comment: Do you have any cronjob running, do you have any user based upload, to you have an infinite foreach somewhere in the code, do you have jobs running in the background or any queues setup?

Comment: I did search for all these things, but did not find anything. Currently I am manually adding logs to suspicious functions.

Comment: Thats it, when you manually add logs it probably upsets the memory limit. So try and develop the logging to happen inside the application by using the pre-built logger Laravel/PHP provides.If you need better overview look into the ELK stack for logging.